# Wordpress theme installation

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

**Question**:Hi, I am working on my blog but when I try to install a theme it always throws error.

**Details:**

1. I was hosting on infinity free, everything worked fine , even the live preview but when I activated and published the theme, whole site was blank(white). I wasn't able to access the dashboard.
2. I tried again on freehosting but got error and the site broke. After trying many times the theme was installed but with the following message:
   **Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /public_html/wp-includes/update.php on line 168**

Things I've tried-

1. Use a different theme.
2. Directly install or copy files in wp-content/theme
3. Change hosting (have two domains on different hosting)

Wordpress version 5.5.1
PHP version 7.3

PS- The themes works perfectly on localhost. They just break on live server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the solution. As I was expecting the problem was with hosting as got different errors on different hosting. Switched to a paid hosting and everything is fine now.